# Odd xcode error when calling defined func in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have the following function defined in a .swift file in a new project I'm creating:

```
func createCircle(xPos: Int, yPos: Int) {
    // do code here
}
```

For some reason when I try to call it using the following code xcode displays an error stating "Missing argument label 'yPos:' in call".

```
createCircle(100, 100)
```

The odd thing is it treats yPos different than xPos - if I include xPos: in the calling function it highlights the line and says "Cannot convert the expression's type '$Tf' to type 'IntegerLiteralConvertable'".  So the following is what I end up with in order to call the aforementioned function:

```
createCircle(100, yPos: 100)
```

Am I missing something obvious or is this an xcode beta bug?

Comment: is this a method inside a class or a function sitting by itself in an external file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Swift documentation

***Section - Methods - Local and External Parameter Names for Methods***

> "Specifically, Swift gives the first parameter name in a method a
>   local parameter name by default, and gives the second and subsequent
>   parameter names both local and external parameter names by default."

Judging from your error, it seems like you're using a method and not a function. You don't need to provide the name for the first parameter but you must for subsequent parameters but this behaviour can be changed with the _ (underscore character).

```
class MyCircle {
    var xPos: Double = 0.0;
    var yPos: Double = 0.0;

    func createCircle(x: Double, _ y: Double) {
        // insert create circle logic here.
    }
}

var cir = MyCircle();
cir.createCircle(100, 100);
```

By using the underscore for subsequent parameters you don't have to provide the label for them when calling the method.